# Sharepoint Desinger 2010 - Transfer Reusable Workflow from Stage to Prod

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I need to transfer a reusable Workflow from the stage env. to the prod.

The workflow is associate to a list, so the list id is stored in the workflow.

Is it possible to transfer the workflow and change the list id to the list name with Visual Studio? (We have no SharePoint Designer access to the prod. env.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

I tried several hours to fix a reusable workflow, which same as yours was associated with a specific list - I switched systems and the GUID changed --> Workflow was broken.

You can give it a try and rename the `MyWorkflow.wsp` to `MyWorkflow.cab` and extract that somewhere. The workflow files are XML based hence you can edit the associated list GUID with your favorite editor. Now you need to package your edited file back into a `cab` file, rename it to `wsp` and you can give it a shot. I tried exactly that and resented to just "re-clicking" (as it's SPD) my workflow (two screens come in handy here).

That's what I call "reusable" workflow... Next time **do not** associate your reusable workflow with anything to keep it reusable.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is, this way is only usable for a small numbers of workflows. Not for a large env. But the idea is great!

Comment: You're very correct. For a large number of workflows use Visual Studio to deploy them via a custom feature. That way you can associate them in any way you like.

Comment: The workflow designer in SPD is handy, but this is one of it's biggest drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating an Content Type in a Feature and then base your list and your Reusable Workflow association on that Content Type. We had a project in December where we successfully used this method. I saved a Reusable Workflow as a template. I then deployed the Content Type solution package and the Workflow solution package to another environment. Worked like a charm.

Comment: How do you handle workflow upgrades when developing on system A and want to deploy version 2 on system B where version 1 is already in production?

Comment: Every time you export a workflow from SharePoint Designer, it creates a solution package with a different solution ID, even if the package name is the same. But I found that if you expand the package after changing .wsp to .cab, change the solution ID back to the original, and put the files back together as a wsp, then you'll have an equivalent solution package that can be deployed as an update to your original.

Comment: Oh, I think you'll also need to change the Guid of the Feature ID. It's been awhile since I've done it, but I think that's it.

Comment: And then you can just deactivate and delete the old solution and upload and activate the new solution and everything works fine? (would surprise me in this cruel SharePoint-World)

Comment: I would try to update the solution first. But if that fails, then try the retract-delete-add-install pattern.

Answer (score 2):

There are tow alternatives for deploying workflow regardless the assigned content types 
It is very simple just do the following:

Alternative One

1. Save the workflow as template
2. Go to the following path in your site
   http://your_server_Address/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx
3. Download the file as WSP
4. Go to the following URL
   http://your_Target_server_Address/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx
5. Upload the WSP, and activate the solution
6. Go to the site settings, then Site Actions, then Manage site features
7. Activate the feature that is related to the workflow
8. If you click workflows under site administration you would be able to see your custom reusable workflow

Alternative Two

1. Save the workflow as template
2. Go to the following path in your site
   http://your_server_Address/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx
3. Download the file as WSP
4. Open your visual studio
5. Click add new project
6. Under SharePoint choose 2010
7. Choose Import reusable work flow
8. Follow the wizard
9. Project will be created and can be deployed

Note : Make sure your workflow is reusable and that it has no errors

Comment: I followed alternative one from step 1-7 and no problem. But on step 8 I cannot see the reusable workflow. I can only see it by connect with SPD and publish the workflow.